# Creating Custom Elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create my own HTML element. Now, before you mark this as a duplicate and downvote it, let me tell you that I am not doing it for styling. I have created my own styling tags, and even answered a stack overflow question about that.

I HAVE seen sites like:

[Is there a way to create your own html tag in HTML5?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUuNTgzOPLAhVESSYKHfTODtwQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2802687%2Fis-there-a-way-to-create-your-own-html-tag-in-html5&usg=AFQjCNG93xF9yekvHcQo_OlfsduPYKCP4g&sig2=ylJ0hphzkJSZ4FyQVoe3YQ)

and

[html5 - how can i create my own HTML tag?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUuNTgzOPLAhVESSYKHfTODtwQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F6164000%2Fhow-can-i-create-my-own-html-tag&usg=AFQjCNED0qdF_bHCsKhnKtgV-0q_AtjiaA&sig2=sF9KTT2LckboG7UTg8nXlA)

but they do not answer my question.

I am attempting to make a "widget" tag. E.G:

```
<submit value='Submit form'></submit>
```

Instead of

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit form'></input>
```

I deal with forms a lot and it is very unorganized and tedious to use the input and type.

Is there any way I could do this?
I would prefer not to use a third-party script like jquery but I can use it if needed.

Comment: Might want to look into something like [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), or Angular's component system.

Comment: Yes, you can as long as you create and register them properly. There are a number of questions on custom elements on SO...try searching for them. That said, you seem to be re-inventing the wheel for very little benefit.

Comment: `"but they do not answer my question"` - Why not?  In what way is that attempt not working as expected?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Creating your own elements is a massive hassle for ***very*** little gain.

Comment: You can use [`<button>Submit form</button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) instead. That uses even fewer characters than your widget.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes I could, but that would not actually submit the form. I could use a function like `function submit(data) { window.open("formhandler.php?stuff="+data);}` but that would only work for GET forms, not POST, which I use commonly

Comment: `<button>` does submit the containing form by default. Read the linked documentation: "The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the [`type`] attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value."

Comment: @Blazemonger Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<button>Submit form</button>` instead. That uses even fewer characters than your widget.

`<button>` submits the containing form by default. [Reading the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button): "The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the [`type`] attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value." – Blazemonger 45 mins ago